# Swift 4 editor issue with Xcode 8 and toolchain set swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I don't know why I've set toolchain to swift4 but still show the wrong message.

Could you help me solve this problem?

[image: editor issue]

[image: toolchain set swift4]

Comment: download xcode 9 beta

Comment: With XCode 9 didn't show the error, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 supports, Swift 4. You should update your Xcode with latest release.

Download Xcode 9 without Paid (Premium) Apple Developer Account from this link. Also update command line tool for Xcode 9 beta.

> [Xcode 9 - Beta 3](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_beta_3/Xcode_9_beta_3.xip)
>     
>  - [(Command Line Tool - Xcode 9 Beta 3)](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9_beta_3/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9_beta_3.dmg)

[Apple Download Portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/)